# Database SQL Dreamweaver connecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, dreamweaver

When i connected mySQL databases to dreamweaver I only saw the default databases, none of the ones I created in myPHPadmin, I am running MAMP 2.2  on Mac OS X 10.7.5 Dreamweaver CS6, I am going to the databases icon on the right side of the screen in "App Developer Plus" viewing mode.  I am trying to add a database  with mySQL connection:

Connection Name: registration, mySQL server: localhost, Username: root, Password: my set password, Database <--- here is the error when I click select; it does not show the databaes I made in myPHP admin. called Registration and Dbank;  I'm expecting to see these databases as I can see them in myPHPadmin.  but in Dreamweaver after connecting to mySQL i only see: information_schema. mysql, performance_schema, and test.

Nothing seemed to work.. so I thought it could be an error created when i had installed mysql before installing MAMP, So i removed mysql standalone, and when I removed mysql, the databases no longer connected at all in dreamweaver.  I got an error:

MySQL Error #2002

No such file or directory so THEN I have tried

1. Formating my computer and reinstalling all Dreamwweaver, MAMP, and re-enabling everything --> SAME ERROR :(
2. Setting the path in terminal to include /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql in .bash_profile  --> SAME ERROR  :(
3. In Terminal doing:

cd /var/

sudo mkdir mysql

cd (to get back to root)

sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock

--> SAME ERROR  :(

Why can't Dreamweaver just connect to the databases.? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: it does connect to a database, just not the one you want it to. You can issue a `SHOW DATABASES` query to view the available databases. And a simple `USE \`DATABASE_NAME\`` to use the one you want.

Comment: Look at This Link.It may help you. > http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/connect-mysql-database-dreamweaver.html